# Implementing message flood protection via JS

Tags: javascript

I'm currently running a server. A bot that I coded currently supplies administrative tools for moderators, but I would like the bot to also have some sort of automated flood-protection system built in.

So I have access to every **message** sent by the user, the **name** of the user that sent the message, and the **time** that they sent the message. I'm not sure how to go about making a system though, does anybody have any ideas? I want to be able to moderate flood-protection for each user in the server.

Comment: Don't use javascript for protection. Use it as a first line of defence, but asume someone has manipulated your code clientside, asume that part javascript is turned off.

Comment: Are you perhaps implying that the server is actually running JavaScript? (ie node)?

Comment: Yes it is using node

Comment: Are you using a server with a middleware API?

Comment: Yes, it's called DiscordJS I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map keyed on username. The value for each user should be a circular array of length `n` (say ten). The contents of each circular array should be a timestamp of the request.

On each inbound request, get the `n`th item from the array for that username. Subtract it from `performance.now()`, then do the math to see if that rate is acceptable. If not, do a no-op, or return an HTPP error code.

The following code is illustrative and not meant to be functional.

```
var Q_LENGTH = 10;
var MAX_REQUEST_RATE = 1; // per second
var requestTimeMap = {};

function onRequest(username, timestamp) {
  recordReq(username);
  if(tooFast(username)) {
      // return HTTP 40x
  }

  // service the request
}

function recordReq(username) {
  requestTimeMap[username] = requestTimeMap.username || createCircularQ(Q_LENGTH); 
  requestTimeMap[username].unshift(performance.now())
}

function tooFast(username) {
  return ((performance.now() - (requestTimeMap[username][Q_LENGTH] || 0)) / Q_LENGTH) > (1000 / MAX_REQUEST_RATE);
}

function createCircularQ(length) {
  var circularQueue = [];    
  circularQueue.unshift = function(element) {
    if (this.length === length) {
      this.pop();
    }
    return Array.prototype.unshift.call(this, element);
  }
  return circularQueue;
}
```